# How to get the execution time of my block in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there a way to extract automatically the execution time of a my block in simulink? the simulink profiler report treats every function separately, whereas I want to get the sum as my block contains many sub-functions.

Comment: I tried running a simple simulink model from Matlab's command line with matlab profiler on. I was able to see total time for functions, but I didn't really recognize anything specific to a certain block...

Comment: I don't think you can, that's not how the Simulink engine works. The profiler is the only way estimate execution time of a model, but not block by block.